# Using widgets outside the sidebar?

Tags: wordpress

Is it possible to use widgets outside of the sidebar? When you assign them in the admin panel you have to drag them to your sidebar but I would like to implement a search function outside the sidebar. Can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Absolutely.  [This thread](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/placing-widgets-outside-of-the-sidebar) in the WordPress support forums should get you going.  It creates a new widget area ready called `Homepage` that can then be used in any of your theme's template files:

**Your theme's functions.php**

```
if (function_exists('register_sidebar')) {
    register_sidebar(array(
        'name'=> 'Main',
        'id' => 'main',
        'before_widget' => '<div class="widget_box side">',
        'after_widget' => '</div>',
        'before_title' => '<h3>',
        'after_title' => '</h3>',
    ));
    register_sidebar(array(
        'name'=> 'Homepage',
        'id' => 'homepage',
        'before_widget' => '<div class="widget_box">',
        'after_widget' => '</div>',
        'before_title' => '<h3>',
        'after_title' => '</h3>',
    ));
}
```

**The template file you want the Homepage widget in**

```
<?php if (function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') && dynamic_sidebar('Homepage')) : ?>
```

Alternatively, you can use the [My Custom Widgets plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/mycustomwidget/) to do the same thing.

Comment: To future people visiting... keep scrolling down

Answer (score 22):

The correct answer is use [the_widget()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_widget)

I used it to integrate a widget into my own custom widget. Check out the [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_widget) for details on how to use it.

Comment: This is the correct answer. It allows you to call the widget without the use of the admin panel.